# Set foot in vs. step foot in

Tags: word-choice

Currently, in everyday language, I hear people use the expression: 'step foot in', rather than the expression: 'set foot in'.  The former expression sounds incorrect while the latter expression sounds correct. Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: Could you please supply example usages. To "step in it" has a very different meaning.

Comment: @Peter: Where do you see "step in it" used in the question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who you're talking to, but historically *set foot in* is represented in the corpus vastly more than *step foot in* is. See this [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+foot+in%2Cstep+foot+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20foot%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstep%20foot%20in%3B%2Cc0) for a comparison.

[image]

Still, what you may be witnessing is an [**eggcorn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn), a mishearing by someone that has been propagated by others, in this case your peers. Here's an NGram that compares two terms: *home in on*, which is an expression originating in the 19th century use of homing pigeons, resurrected in WWII to describe guided weapons technology; and *hone in on*, an eggcorn that has taken on a life of its own, and is now even included in dictionaries (some even argue that the eggcorn is an improvement).

[image]

You could argue that *step foot in* is an improvement on *set foot in*, one that sets it closer to the mark, since stepping is what feet do; or you might suppose that *step foot in* is actually an alteration in meaning from that phrase: to *step foot in* something adds a wry twist to the process, reminiscent of someone stepping into, say, a manure pile.

In this respect it could be similar to saying

> "We'll fall off that bridge when we come to it"

eliciting a laugh when the listener expects you to say

> "We'll *cross* that bridge when we come to it.

So *step foot in* might be said to get a laugh. Either way, if you're hearing that more and more, it may be the process described above. You might ask the people you hear it from to tell you whether they mean you to take it ironically or at face value.

Comment: One might also point out that "step" is not generally a transitive verb.  One doesn't "step foot in" a place, one simply steps in it.

Comment: From the standpoint of phonetics, there is an awful lot of similarity between _step foot on_ and _set foot on_. For starts, at ordinary speech rates, whatever stop ends the first word is going to be omitted before /f/. So the only difference is the initial /s/ versus /st/ in a syllable that doesn't have main stress: [ˌsɛ'fʊɾɔn] versus [ˌstɛ'fʊɾɔn]. They would be hard to distinguish under almost any circumstances.